# R: Mathematical Function Expression to String

Tags: r

I want to  use the `rARS()` function from the "AdapSamp" package in R in order to sample from several un-normalized desity functions. However, the formula in `rARS(n, formula, min = -Inf, max = Inf, sp)` must be a string/character of form e.g. `"exp(-(x-2)^2/(2*4))"` but what I have are several functions of form e.g.
`density <- function(x){ exp(-(x-2)^2/(2*4)) }`, for which I have to pre-specify the parameters like the mean 2 in this example.

What is the easiest way here to translate a mathematical expression to such a string expression?

Using `as.character( exp(-(x-2)^2/(2*4)) )` only gives me a list of value characters. I think one could manage it by deparsing the function which is then to be pre-specfied in advance, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide the input you have.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
> f <- function(x){ exp(-(x-2)^2/(2*4)) }
> as.character(body(f))[2]
[1] "exp(-(x - 2)^2/(2 * 4))"
```

Comment: Thanks! This partially helps and is what I meant by using deparse like deparse(f)[3]. Anyway, further solutions are welcome!

Comment: @K.O.T. This provides the string you asked for, so why do you want further solutions? Why does it "partially" help? You should be clearer about your expectation, I think.